# Sql Server Performance Issue with link and join

Tags: sql-server

Which one gives better performance on a large set of records???

```
select  name from tablea,tableb where tablea.id = tableb.id
```

Or

```
select name from tablea inner join tableb on tablea.id = tableb.id
```

Here I have given a simple example, but in our project we use a lot of tables and joins to fetch records. In this more complicated case, which one wil give higher performance, links or joins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. You should always use ANSI joins, in any case.

There are more than just style considerations for using ANSI joins:

- In future versions of SQL Server, non-standard joins may not be supported.
- You cannot perform all types of joins using old-style syntax. For example, the following ANSI-style query:

  ```
  SELECT
  FROM
      dbo.Customer C
      LEFT JOIN dbo.Address A
          ON C.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
          AND A.AddressType = 'Home' -- this can't be done with non-ANSI
  WHERE
      A.CustomerID IS NULL
  ;
  ```
- Using `JOIN` expresses the intent of the query more clearly to the developer, by separating conditions that are specific to the mechanics of how tables always relate to each other in the `JOIN` clause, and putting conditions that are specific to the needs of *this* query in the `WHERE` clause. Putting all the conditions, joining and filtering, in the `WHERE` clause clutters the `WHERE` clause and makes it exceedingly hard to understand complex queries.
- Using `JOIN` allows the conditions that join a table to be physically near where that table is introduced in the script, reducing the likelihood of making mistakes and further aiding comprehension.

I will state absolutely and categorically that **you will gain no performance benefit from using old-style joins instead of ANSI joins**. If a query using `ANSI` joins is too complex for the optimizer to do a good job, it is only a matter of chance whether the old-style join will work better or worse. The reverse is exactly as true, that if a query using old-style joins is too complex for the optimizer to do a good job, then it is only a matter of chance whether an ANSI join will work better or worse.

The *correct* solution to queries that are not performing well is for an expert to study the query, the tables, and the underlying indexes and make recommendations. The query may benefit from being separated into two (first inserting to a temp table, then joining to that). There may be missing indexes. Data types may be chosen poorly. A clustered index may need to move from the `PK` to another column. The conditions on the query might be transformable to SARGable ones. Date functions on newly-introduced columns might be eliminated in favor of date inequality conditions against pre-calculable expressions using constants or earlier-introduced columns. There may be denormalization that is actually hurting performance.

There are a host of factors that can affect performance, and I guarantee you with every shred of conviction I possess that going back to old-style joins will never, ever be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In that simplified example, the performance should be exactly the same. If you run Query Analyzer on the two options, you'll see that the optimizer will translate your WHERE into a JOIN in any case.

You might be able to write a query complex enough to confound the optimizer, though, so stick with JOINs.

Comment: here i given a simple example. In our Project we used lot of tables and joins to fetch records. in this case which one is give high performance links or joins?

Comment: I already told you, @user3875617, that neither one will "give high performance." Stop thinking this way--you're heading down the path of failure. Please see my updated post.